# WiFi issue on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wireless, hp, realtek-wireless

I have an HP laptop dual booted with windows 10 and Ubuntu16.04 LTS.
WiFi on Windows works just fine but when I switch to Ubuntu, the network which was showing **strong** connection in Windows shows **weak** in Ubuntu. Sometimes it also refuses to connect. Can you please help?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this,

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

### **OR**

This done not working fine try below,

Hi, The special version 2 is for 64bit Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 14.04 and above
use the regular **broadcom-kernel-source** driver. From a working wired connection...
Please open a terminal .. ctrl+alt+t .. and do...

> Ignore file not found or errors..`

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge broadcom-kernel-source
sudo rm -rf bcma
```

then do,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then install the wl driver..

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall broadcom-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -v wl
```

Comment: There is no package named `broadcom-kernel-source` and what does Broadcom have to do with the OP's Realtek wireless?